# Is sister eligible for US green card "through your family"?

Tags: family

If I am an immigrant and I have acquired a Green card, is my sister (divorced and living alone in India) eligible for "*US Green card through your family*"

Or do only parents, kids and spouse fall under that option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to be a US citizen who is 21 or over to petition a sibling or parent to immigrate to the US.

Comment: Thanks. So what is the maximum tenure that a Permanent resident may invite his sibling to the USA? I have accepted your answer, but unable to upvote you. Don't know why?

Comment: @RichaSharma Are you asking how long a sibling could visit you in the USA?

Comment: Yes, That's right.

Comment: @RichaSharma - According to the answer you accepted, it depends on whether you are at least 21. // I think you can't upvote an answer until you reach something like 15 rep. // Perhaps this would be helpful: https://my.uscis.gov/exploremyoptions/us_petition_for_other_family_members_inside_us